# Background image does not appear on screen

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to run code from a tutorial I found online.

But when I run this code, my background image does not appear, even if it loaded correctly.

Why?

```
bif = "castle.jpg"
import pygame, sys, pygame.mixer

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,960),0, 32)

background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
pygame.display.set_caption("castlevania ultimate")

hit_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("02.wav")
hit = False

if hit is True:
    hit_sound.play()

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("castlevania_1.wav")
sound.play()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call `pygame.display.update()` in your `while` loop.

Python is indentation sensitive, so the loop should look like this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Note that `pygame.display.update()` is now *inside* the `while` loop.